# How to sort this type of dictionary in python2

Tags: python, python-2.7

`deli = {'deli1': 'bbb', 'deli': 'aaa', 'deli3': 'ccc'}`

How to get the dictionary sorted through key

Finally, the printing results of value are as follows.

`aaa, bbb, ccc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the values corresponding with sorted keys, just iterate over the sorted keys and lookup the value:

```
for key in sorted(deli):
    print deli[key]
```

would output:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python2x, the order of the keys is not ensured. So you've to use OrderedDict if you want to maintain the order of keys in the dictionary (or a tuple of tuples).

```
import collections

sorted_deli = collections.OrderedDict()

for key in sorted(deli):
    sorted_deli[key] = deli[key]

print(sorted_deli.values())
```